# Call parent object method inside function with callback handler

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm calling ParentObject.doSomething() which inturn calls the WebService object to perform some ajax calls, and on success of the ajax call, the callback function is executed. But any parent function inside the callback function fails.

I think this has something to do with scope resolution. I am not able to find a workaround for this problem.

Is there a better architectural style to modularize the ajax services and model?

I've create a jsfiddle also - http://jsfiddle.net/bzKXr/2/

```
var ParentObject =  {

     doSomething: function(){
         document.write("Inside doSomething <br />");
         var self = this;
         WebServices.firstService("some URL", self.successCallback);
     },

     changeData: function(data){
         //Manipulate data
         document.write("Inside changeData <br />");
     },

     successCallback: function(jsonData){
         document.write("Inside successCallback <br />");
         try {
             //Execution fails at this point. Possibly because of scope resolution
             this.changeData(jsonData);  
         }
         catch (error) {
             console.log(error);
             document.write(error);
         }  
     },
};

var WebServices = {
    firstService: function(url, successCallbackHandler){
        document.write("Inside firstService <br />");
        //Get data using the URL
        //on success call successCallback
        successCallbackHandler("some data");
    }
};


$(document).ready(function() {
    ParentObject.doSomething();

});
​
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Writing `self.successCallback` doesn't bind the function to `self`, you have to actually *call* the function as `self.successCallback()` to bind the context correctly.

You can do that easily by wrapping the call in a closure which retains access to `self`:

```
doSomething: function(){
     document.write("Inside doSomething <br />");
     var self = this;
     WebServices.firstService("some URL", function() {
        self.successCallback();
     });
 },
```

or in ES5 you can use `.bind()` which ensures that the `this` context for `successCallback` is always the specified parameter:

```
doSomething: function(){
     document.write("Inside doSomething <br />");
     WebServices.firstService("some URL", this.successCallback.bind(this));
 },
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the prettiest way to do it:

```
WebServices.firstService("some URL", this.successCallback.bind( this ));
```

However, it's not cross-browser. (read: IE8 and below can't use it)

This is why jQuery has [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
WebServices.firstService("some URL", $.proxy( this.successCallback, this ));
```

Answer (score 1):

When the callback function is called, the `this` is not valid. In javascript, if a function is called with `foo.bar()`, `this` will be set to `foo`, but if you just call `foo()`, the previously set `this` will be kept, in your case the element of the event, probably your `WebService`.
To avoid this, you must use closures. You can replace `this.changeData(jsonData);` by `ParentObject.changeData(jsonData);`. Closures means than a function can access variable in the scope where the function was defined, so your function can access ParenObject.

A more elegant way could be:

```
var ParentObject =  {

    doSomething: function(){
        document.write("Inside doSomething <br />");
        var self = this;
        WebServices.firstService("some URL", function(jsonData) {
            document.write("Inside successCallback <br />");
            self.changeData(jsonData);
        }
    },

    changeData: function(data){
        //Manipulate data
        document.write("Inside changeData <br />");
    }
};
```

You callback function is defined directly in you `doSomething` function, so you have access to the variable `self` defined in it, and can call `self.changeData()`.

Answer (score 0):

if you change `this.changeData(jsonData);` to `ParentObject.changeData(jsonData);` it should work.

The reason for the error is that the `this` variable no longer refers to `ParentObject` when the AJAX call returns.

An alternative approach is to store a reference to `this` inside another variable (by convention called `that`) and change your code to say `that.changeData(jsonData);`

Comment: an object should never need to reference its own name...  This code will fail if there's more than one instance of this class.

Comment: @Alnitak - there are no classes in JavaScript, only objects. In the code above there is a single object called ParentObject, so I don't see an issue.

Comment: class/function, whatever.  My point is that you're tying together the _internals_ of the function with whatever name that function happens to have _externally_.  This is poor design, and unnecessary.

Comment: If the OPs code was written differently (eg if the successCallback was defined outside ParentOject, and assigned as a method to multiple different objects) then I agree that would be a valid concern.

Comment: oh I give up.  Your solution _designs in_ a restriction that is unnecessary.

Comment: Don't give up! This type of discussion is exactly what this site is for. I've found your comments useful, thank you :)

Comment: oh alright, then.  Essentially, there's _nothing_ in that object that implies it's a singleton.  Using its name _inside_ of it will prevent  multiple instances from being created.  It also requires that the internals have to be changed if the external name ever changes.  There's just no need for it.

Comment: But how would you go about creating a second ParentObject? Surely doing so would need some kind a factory function to make multiple copies, which the OP doesn't have.

Comment: `var o = Object.create(ParentObject)`

Comment: Cool - I didn't know you could do that! I will need to look at all the other goodies coming along in ES5. Thanks again!

Comment: "coming along"?  ES5 has been standardised since Dec 2009!  It's just that certain browsers are only just catching up...

Answer (score 0):

Another possiblitity is change

```
WebServices.firstService("some URL", self.successCallback);
```

to

```
WebServices.firstService("some URL", function(data){ return self.successCallback(data) });
```

The basic problem is that, unlike Python, methods Javascript in Javascript forget about their owner object as soon as you pass them somewhere else or set another variable.